# Java stack overflow on computing SCC on large graph

Tags: java, graph, stack, stack-overflow

I have a graph with close to 1 mil nodes, on which I am computing the strongly connected components.  I have increased the heap size of the vm to 10240 mb, but it is still throwing this exception  :

```
Error: 875714
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.Stack.push(Stack.java:67)
```

I am absolutely sure that code is not the issue, but the size.  What else can I do?

UPDATE : The StackOverflowError is thrown regardless of the heap size I set the vm, after 6 seconds.

If I can't solve the StackOverflowError on StackOverflow.com, I don't know where else to turn =)

Comment: You'll need to include some more code.  If you are using recursive calls, you'll probably need to change your code to use a regular loop.

Comment: Well, why don't you increase stack size for a start? Google it.

Comment: The heap size cannot have an effect on StackOverflowErrors, since thread stack memory is not part of the heap. You can increase the thread stack size, but that's a different JVM option, -Xss I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind, that `StackOverflowError` has nothing to do with `java.util.Stack`: the error is thrown when there is no more space for call stack (i.e. too deep recursion), not when there is no space in `Stack` object.

The first thing I suggest is to revise the algorithm. My blind guess is you are using recursion for visiting neighbor nodes, which causes the overflow. Try to use loops in place of recursion.

For short-term purpose you can also try increasing stack size (not heap size) with `-Xss`. BTW, keep in mind that each thread has its own stack.

Answer (score 0):

Do not confuse a `StackOverflowError` with an `OutOfMemoryError`.  A `StackOverflowError` occurs "[when an application recurses too deeply](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html)," whereas an `OutOfMemoryError` occurs when "[no more memory could be made available by the garbage collector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html)."

Since you're getting `StackOverflowError`s, try to find a location where you can convert some recursion to a loop.  That should help.